# How is it possible to correctly define XML elements with define_method?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, nokogiri

I'm using the following snippet to create some XML and it works absolutely fine.

```
def outputs_xml(dir, t_items, x)
  x.murders {
    t_items.values.each do |i|
      x.murder {
        attributes_xml(dir, i, x)
      }
    end
  }
end
```

The XML produced looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<outputs>
  <murders>
    <murder>
      <classification>Macabre</classification>
      <title>An Old Macabre Murder</title>
      <path>C:\an_old_macabre_murder.pdf</path>
    </murder>
  </murders>
</outputs>
```

Attempting to refine this with `define_method` means that the attributes are not "translated" (for want of a better word). Instead of using the type (e.g. 'murders') the XML now reads 'type'.

```
["murders", "mysteries", "thrillers"].each do |type|
  define_method("#{type}_xml") do |dir, items, o|
    x.type {
      items.values.each do |i|
        o.type.singularize{
          o.classification i[1].to_s
          o.titles i[2]
          o.path "#{dir}/#{i[3]}.pdf"
        }
      end
    }
  end
```

...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<outputs>
  <type>
    <type class="singularize">
      <classification>Macabre</classification>
      <title>An Old Macabre Murder</title>
      <path>C:\an_old_macabre_murder.pdf</path>
    </type>
  </type>
</outputs>
```

To summarize: in the original code I was able to iterate through a hash and use 'x.murder' to produce `<murder>...</murder>` but with `define_method` the same code produces `<type>` with attributes.

How is it possible to correctly define the element with `define_method`?

Comment: You intention of use `define_method` is not clear to me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually calling `x.type` and `o.type.singularize` instead of calling `x.murders` and `o.murder`.
Since Nokogiri works by utilizing `method_missing`, I believe you should use `x.send` instead:

```
["murders", "mysteries", "thrillers"].each do |type|
define_method("#{type}_xml") do |dir, items, o|
  x.send(type) {
    items.values.each do |i|
      o.send(type.singularize) {
        o.classification i[1].to_s
        o.titles i[2]
        o.path "#{dir}/#{i[3]}.pdf"
      }
    end
  }
end
```

When you want to call a method *dynamically* you cannot simply put the variable name as a method name, and hope it will be called:

```
a = 'to_i'
'123'.a # <= ERROR - _not_ '123'.to_i
```

Ruby's [send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-send) API enables you to do that, by passing the method name as an argument:

> Invokes the method identified by *symbol*, passing it any arguments
>   specified. You can use `__send__` if the name send clashes with an
>   existing method in obj. When the method is identified by a string, the
>   string is converted to a symbol.

```
a = 'to_i'
'123'.send(a) # => 123
```

Comment: In `x.send(type.to_sym) `, you can write as `x.send(type) `.. `#send` understands both.. *string* and *symbol*.

Comment: Thank you - works as needed. Would you please advise why `send` works? I understand what's happening with `method_missing`, but why use `send` specifically?

Comment: added explanation about the `send` method